# Django admin add object field error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

Django version: 1.8.4
Python version: 2.7.10
My django model like these:
kind/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Kind(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, default="default kind name")
    create_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_created=True)
```

game/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from kind import models as kind_models

class Game(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    kind = models.ForeignKey(kind_models.Kind)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, default="default game")
    description = models.TextField(null=False, default="default description")
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_created=True, auto_now=True)
    sale_date = models.DateField()
```

game/amdin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from game import models as game_models

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'get_kind', 'name', 'description', 'create_date', 'sale_date')
    search_fields = ('id', 'get_kind', 'name', 'description', 'create_date', 'sale_date')
    list_filter = ('kind__name', 'name', 'create_date', 'sale_date')
    ordering = ('id',)
    fields = ('id', 'get_kind', 'name', 'description', 'sale_date')

    def get_kind(self, obj):
        return obj.kind.name

    get_kind.short_description = 'kind'
    get_kind.empty_value_display = 'not value set'

admin.site.register(game_models.Game, AuthorAdmin)
```

I run my application successfully and view admin without any error or warning. But when I click `add game`, the web page show me some error like these:

```
FieldError at /admin/game/game/add/
Unknown field(s) (get_kind) specified for Game. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class AuthorAdmin.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/admin/game/game/add/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Unknown field(s) (get_kind) specified for Game. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class AuthorAdmin.
```

In fact, I am not good at django, I'm just a django beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set `get_kind` as `search_fields` and `fields`, but this is not an actual field on your model. You can't do that (especially in fields, because you can't assign something to function). You should specify `kind__name` in `search_fields` and `kind` in `fields` instead.

If you really want to display value from column, you can make it as property in your model and put it in `read_only`.

Comment: I set `fields = ("kind")`, but it show me lots of string value `kind object` when I add a game record. What should I do?

Comment: You should specify `__str__` method (or `__unicode__` on python 2.7) in `Kind` model that will just return meaningful string (for example name of kind).

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the model object as "get_kind" in your Django admin when the model object itself is just "kind". So like with your "fields=" in admin it should be fields=('id', 'kind', 'name'....etc

Comment: I know that set `fields=('kind')` will no error, but it show me lots of string value `kind object` when I add a game record. It is not the result that I wanna.